# How do ketone react with a peroxy acid to yield an ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

This may be a really dumb question but I can't find any mechanism plot or reasoning how ketone reacts with carboxylic acid and form an ester. I thought R-OH react with RC(O)OOH to form ester..

I tried several iterations to solve the following question. Please let me know how to solve it properly.

[image]

Comment: That's not a carboxylic acid; a carboxylic acid only has *two* oxygens. This has one more oxygen. Search in your favourite book, or online, for the Baeyer–Villiger reaction. That should answer most of the question, if not all.

Comment: Wikipedia is as a good a place to start as any  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baeyer%E2%80%93Villiger_oxidation